# Hibernate Validator Depends on

Tags: hibernate-validator, javax.validation

Is there a way to achieve depends on behavior with hibernate validation. For instance if i have two custom validations

```
@InvalidAmount // Validates the amount is invalid with some custom logic
@AmountNotAccepted // Validates the currency is not accepted along with some custom logic
```

The idea is not to merge both of them together and throw second error only if the first one succeeds. Is there a way to do it? Something like run the second validate only first first is not an error.

For example:

```
@AmountNotAccepted(dependsOn = {InvalidAmount})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be after [group sequences](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-defining-group-sequences)?

Comment: I am afraid that group sequence would not work. All the annotations belong to the default group by default